# Javascript +/- with quantity limit

Tags: javascript, opencart

I have been wracking by brains trying to find a solution for this by searching many, many posts. I have a free script that ads plus / minus buttons to Opencart product pages for the quantity field. I need to limit this to 10 (maximum products). I tried to get this to work by adding;

```
document.getElementById("quantity").maxLength = "1";
```

Which only allows one character, so maximum number is 9 (close enough). But this only works if typing into the text area, clicking on the + button will still increase the quantity?

This is the javascript;

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(function(){$("#quantity").parent().children().css("vertical-align","middle")});
function btnminus(a){document.getElementById("quantity").value>a?document.getElementById("quantity").value--:document.getElementById("quantity").value=a}
function btnplus(){document.getElementById("quantity").value++};
//--></script>
```

This is the html;

```
<img alt="" src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/minus.png" border="0" style="cursor:pointer;display:inline-block;" onclick="btnminus(<?php echo $minimum; ?>);">
<input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" size="2" value="<?php echo $minimum; ?>" />
<img alt="" src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/plus.png" border="0" style="cursor:pointer;display:inline-block;" onclick="btnplus();">
```

I have little understanding of Javascript, everything I try just breaks the code. Any help greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: All this needs is a simple check for current value before increasing or decreasing it … (Plus a `parseInt` thrown in, otherwise it would likely be using string concatenation instead of addition.)

Comment: Thanks very much for the info, but I am very new to javascript. I pretty much only play around with html & css. I tried to adapt the "btminus" part of the code but everything i did just breaks the code.

Would you have an example of code I could experiment with? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to follow the way you have implemented to control the minimum. The opposite is for the maximum..

```
<img alt="" src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/minus.png" border="0" style="cursor:pointer;display:inline-block;" onclick="btnminus(<?php echo $minimum; ?>);">
<input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" size="2" value="<?php echo $minimum; ?>" />
<img alt="" src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/plus.png" border="0" style="cursor:pointer;display:inline-block;" onclick="btnplus(<?php echo $maximum; ?>);">

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(function(){$("#quantity").parent().children().css("vertical-align","middle")});
function btnminus(a){document.getElementById("quantity").value>a?document.getElementById("quantity").value--:document.getElementById("quantity").value=a}
function btnplus(a){document.getElementById("quantity").value<a?document.getElementById("quantity").value++:document.getElementById("quantity").value=a}
//--></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I did try adapting the minimum but I am having trouble defining a value for the maximum. I can not get it to increment beyond 1. 

Any ideas? Thanks again

Comment: @Stoto Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aeuLx9nt/ . I manually added the minimum and maximum values that you add from php.

Comment: @ plbsam That is so cool...:) I get it now, I was trying to set the maximum within the value in the JS. But it can be done using the onclick function. Awesome, seems to be working perfect now...Thanks very much...:)